# Testing react-native audio playback app in Firebase Test Lab

Tags: react-native, firebase-test-lab, react-native-video, react-native-sound

I have a react-native app the main function of which is playback of sound files stored on Azure as blobs. I am focusing on Android deployment.

On my phone the app works fine. I've also initiated Play Console internal and closed tests jointly with around 30-40 users. Only 2 of those users reported a problem whereby the playback stops after a few seconds. One of the users has Galaxy S20 FE.

I originally used react-native-sound for playback. To fix the issue I tried changing to react-native-video hoping that streaming would work. However, the 2 users are still experiencing the problem.

I thought I could use Firebase Test Lab to test the app on more devices. However, here are my problems:

1. Whenever in Android Studio I try to create robo script (Tools->Firebase->Test Lab), the app gets built in Metro mode and when it runs on my phone, I see only the error message to connect metro. How to overcome this?
2. How can I test if sound is playing through Firebase Test Lab?

Any suggestions what might be the reason for the underlying problem or what strategies I can follow to debug the issue further?

Marcin